# Using variables in PostgreSQL function

Tags: function, postgresql, variables, navicat

I get this error when I try to run a custom PostgreSQL function:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
```

PostgreSQL functions are very new for me. I am working with Navicat for PostgreSQL 11.0.17.

I have a table named translations with three columns: id, english, français. Here is how I create my function in the Console window:

```
test=# CREATE FUNCTION add_translation(english varchar(160), français varchar(160))
  RETURNS integer 
  AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  translation_id integer;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO translations
          ("english", "français")
   VALUES (english, français)
RETURNING id
       AS translation_id;
   RETURN translation_id;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

When I call this from the Console window, I get a not-very-useful error message.

```
test=# add_translation('one', 'un');
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "add_translation"
LINE 1: add_translation('one', 'un')
        ^
```

When I call it from the Design Function window, I get the error quoted at the top.

I specifically want to isolate translation_id, because in the final version of this function I want to insert the latest id from the translation table into a new record in a different table.

I have also tried with:

```
DECLARE
  translation_id integer;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO translations
          ("english", "français")
   VALUES (english, français);
  SELECT LASTVAL() INTO translation_id;
  RETURN translation_id;
END;
```

When I run this from the Design Function panel, it behaves correctly, but when I call it from the console I get the same error as before.

If you can recommend any good tutorials and examples for understanding how to use variables correctly in postgres functions, I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the console you need a `select` command

```
select add_translation('one', 'un');
```

or

```
select * from add_translation('one', 'un');
```

Your function can be plain SQL

```
create or replace function add_translation (
    english varchar(160), français varchar(160)
) returns integer as $body$
    insert into translations ("english", "français")
    values (english, français)
    returning id as translation_id;
$body$ language sql;
```

In plpgsql a `setof` some type must be "returned from" the query

```
create or replace function add_translation (
    english varchar(160), français varchar(160)
) returns setof integer as $body$
begin
    return query
    insert into translations ("english", "français")
    values (english, français)
    returning id as translation_id;
end;
$body$ language plpgsql;
```

Or to return a single value do the insert inside a CTE

```
create or replace function add_translation (
    english varchar(160), français varchar(160)
) returns integer as $body$
declare
  translation_id integer;
begin
    with i as (
        insert into translations ("english", "français")
        values (english, français)
        returning id
    )
    select id into translation_id from i;
    return translation_id;
end;
$body$ language plpgsql;
```